# Autocomplete not working correctly in Android Studio with Flutter - First suggestions are irrelevant

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, autocomplete

I installed Flutter and Android Studio.
I ran flutter doctor - [Flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLiUe.png)

I have the Dart plugin installed - v191.8593.
[image]

When I press Ctrl + Space at a very obvious place the AutoComplete do not suggest the right suggestions.
Example:

[View animation here](https://gyazo.com/51578a3d83a6f1f07d2d9335b3dc03ec)

As you see the first suggestion are not of type ScrollPhysics and are out of context,
and after I scroll down, there are ScrollPhysics suggestions, but they are after some scrolling.

Comment: I believe I've ran into this when there were some parser errors in the file. Try fixing all parser errors including the completion location, wait a moment, and then editing the completion location again.

Comment: Have you tried this with VSCode and it gives the same suggestion list?

Comment: @hola, What do you mean by parsing errors?

Comment: @sudo_kaizen In VSCode this is the same.

Answer (score 28):

This problem can be fixed by one of the following

1. Invalidate caches and Restart fixed my problem.
   Goto

> `File-> Ivalidate caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart`

2. Restart Dart Analysis Server. Follow the pic below
   [image]

Note all above solutions works but are not permanent as it appears there is bug in latest dart Analysis server you can follow subscribe to [this reported issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44321) for more updates

Comment: I believe this is the right answer to this question, I was experiencing exactly the same issue and this fixed it.

Comment: this is the right answer,it should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 14):

Restart Dart Analysis Server :-

1. Navigate to **Dart Analysis** tab at bottom.
2. Click **Restart** Icon (red colored icon on top left corner of Dart Analysis Window)
3. Wait for dart analysis to finish.

If it does not work, try this :-

1. Delete **.packages** and **pubspec.lock** files present in your project folder
2. run `flutter pub get`

Comment: this solution worked for me. tnx

Answer (score 14):

[image: Enable scope Analysis]
I fix this by enable the Scope Analysis, at Dart Analysis-> Set Icon-> CheckBox.

Comment: This was my problem. Works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I run in android studio terminal:

```
 flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove Flutter And Dart Plugins and reinstall it will work for suggestion like stateless and stateful widgets if this don't work then remove all the plugins and reinstall will do!

- I remove all of my plugin which I added my self don't remove plugins which was install by android studio IDE.

Answer (score 0):

if you type stful it gives you the autocompletion of stateful widget for you.
or you have to go to

**> Setting -> Editor -> Live Templates ->(choose)Flutter->(tick the option)stful**

[This is the image Depicting the Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JKAP.jpg)

Comment: To help your answer be more clear, try adding so more details to your solution. E.g. where do you type 'stful'?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by changing the first letter of my project directory's name from capital letter to lowercase letter.
Example : "My_project" => "my_project"

The solution was found there : https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5978

Answer (score 0):

First check in **Android Studio** > *Settings* > **Editor** > **Live Templates** that is it empty or not.

If it's empty then
Make sure you have installed latest version of android studio and autosuggestion is on.

For checking if autosuggestion is on or not follow the steps given below;
**Android Studio** > *Settings* > **Editor** > **General** > **Code Completion**

And finally follow below steps:
Go to **Android studio** > **File** > **Manage IDE Settings** > **Restore Default Settings**

Comment: The One and only working solution , thanks

Answer (score -1):

In my case, restart `android-studio` worked.