# Flutter Text Widget doesn't appear

Tags: flutter, text, widget

I'm learning to code and have only just started so apologies if this is a very simple question. In Android Studio when I type 'text' the text widget doesn't come up in the options and can't then get text in the code.
This wasn't an issue for 'MarketApp' or 'Home'. Both widgets came up without an issue. But when I type in 'text' my options start with 'TextDirectionToAxisDirection' and then 'Element.textarea()' and more options come up that don't have the simple text widget. The code is below:

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: text,));

Sorry if this is really simple but as I said I'm learning to code and I wasn't sure how to proceed. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi that's interesting, I wonder if this is of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59848513/autocomplete-not-working-correctly-in-android-studio-with-flutter-first-sugges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just check your problem.

It's because Android studio is case sensitive.

Start typing `Text` with an uppercase `T` and you're done

Comment: You're welcome :) can you accept my answer and upvote it please

Comment: New users don't start with upvoting privileges.

Comment: Stating the obvious in case it helps: You do need to pass the text constructor a string: ```void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Text('hello world'),));```