# Flutter - Icons list is taking long time to load in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Icons list is taking a long time to load in android studio. This is only happening for the icons. The colors list for example is fast and there is no problem with it.

**Screenshot of the issue:**

[image]

Comment: try to read this solution maybe will solve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59848513/autocomplete-not-working-correctly-in-android-studio-with-flutter-first-sugges

Comment: @AHMADAR I tried all of them and still not fixed.

Comment: this issue starts from flutter v2.5 and above