# Flutter/Android Studio: Code Completion not working properly anymore

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I upgraded my Flutter to 3.x and AndroidStudio from 4.x to 2021.x a few months ago.

Since that moment I was not able to use the auto completion anymore. The auto completion **only suggests things from the current file** or explicitly already imported files. But using the feature to **auto import other classes is not possible** anymore. I have to manually find the package paths and import the required classes. This happens not only with external libs but also with my own classes in the project.

I **do not use PowerSave** mode.

I cleared/removed following caches and directories as suggested in several similar questions:

```
Gradle (Windows: user/.gradle)
Pub cache (Windows: user/appdata/local/pub)
Android Studio
    Windows: 
        user/.android
        user/appdata/local/google/androidstudioX
            caches
            compiler
            compiler-server
            conversion
            frameworks
IntelliJ (Project Path ./.idea)
Build Path (Project Path ./build)
```

My flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.7, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2251], locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 3.3.7 on channel stable at E:\Android\Flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision e99c9c7cd9 (4 weeks ago), 2022-11-01 16:59:00 -0700
    • Engine revision 857bd6b74c
    • Dart version 2.18.4
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at E:\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = E:\Android\sdk
    • Java binary at: E:\Android\Android Studio 2021.3.1 RC 1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at E:\Android\Android Studio 2021.3.1 RC 1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2251]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 107.0.5304.107
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 103.0.1264.44
    ! Device emulator-5554 is not authorized.
      You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog.

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

**Edit:**

Interesting observation: With an much older version of the project, it works fine.

Can a project become too big? `lib` directory contains > 1.000 files at the moment.

**Edit2:**

It works in pure IntelliJ (with installed Flutter/Dart plugins).

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59848513/autocomplete-not-working-correctly-in-android-studio-with-flutter-first-sugges

Comment: @Abhijith As stated, I already cleared every cache, so yes, Reinvalidate was done several times. But the hint with the "Dart Analyzer" was new to me. But this did not help anyway :(

Comment: this is happen to me since flutter 3.0.1, but now its work again, try update your flutter plugins into 71.0.3 and flutter version to latest 3.3.9 channel stable

Comment: Flutter Doctor says you don't have the Flutter or Dart plugins installed. What happens if you install those?

Comment: @TarHalda Where do you see it? It only says, not installed VisualStudio. First block says: Flutter 3.3.7, Dart 2.18.4

Comment: @SayyidJ Unfortunately, this didn't help...

Comment: Under the Android Studio heading, it says:

Comment: • Android Studio at E:\Android\Android Studio 2021.3.1 RC 1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

Comment: @S-Man The Flutter and Dart plugins can be installed, meaning they aren't installed.

Comment: @TarHalda Hm, they definitely exist. Android Studio shows: Dart 221.6008.17 and Flutter 71.1.4. Beside the described problem, everything works fine. So complete support for Flutter and Dart is available (beside the autocompletion problem).

Comment: @S-Man that's weird. Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the plugins?

Comment: @TarHalda Yes, I updated, downgraded, installed, reinstalled everything...

Comment: @TarHalda Interesting observation: With an much older version of the project, it works fine.

Can a project become too big? lib directory contains > 1.000 files at the moment

Comment: @S-Man That's a good guess, at least. Over 1K files in lib definitely sounds like it could cause the problem you're describing.

Comment: @TarHalda But then it's not clear to me, why everything worked fine before the Flutter/Android Studio upgrade... I am searching for the missing point, which made the old AS version running better than the the new AS version...

Comment: could you please double check `file > power saved mode`

Comment: @Sajjad ;) I double and triple checked it over and over again...

Comment: New observation: It works in pure IntelliJ (with installed Flutter/Dart plugins).

Comment: did you find any solution? you question is very important.

Comment: @Sajjad No, I created a request on flutter-intellij Github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/6470 but the only workaround atm is to use pure IntelliJ to write code code, which works... in more cases (but, as I observed not in general...)